# Hyper-v core 2016 can't login on domain controller

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, windows-server-core

My windows hyper-v core 2016 was connected to my DC from begining. Suddenly i make update and then i lose connection to my DC. I checked my network config etc. ip and look like it should. I run ipconfig /flushdns && /registerdns didn't work, deleted updates didn't work etc.

Can somebody come with suggestions what todo becuase i run out of solutions.

thanks

Comment: Can you give us more information about what is not working? Are you getting an error when you login to the machine via a domain account and if so what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, i get this error 

Add-Computer : Computer 'DELLVM' failed to join domain 'alfa.local' from its current workgroup 'alfa.local' with follow
ing error message: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Computer -DomainName "alfa.local"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (DELLVM:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand

Comment: Can you ping alfa.local?

Comment: no I can't but ip address yes. Right now I'm not connected to domain because I removed and added again and found out that I couldn't login

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS issue.  You need to be able to ping the domain by name to join/login to a domain. Run ipconfig /all from the affected machine and make sure the windows DNS servers IP address is listed under DNS servers.  No other dns should be in the list.

Comment: I have 2 NIC's 1 is domain networking and second is for DMZ networking. Will that make conflict with dns ?

Comment: You should only define dns setting on one nic card.  Plus, you should only have a default gateway defined one of the default of the nics.  You will then need to use routing and remote access to define routes.

Comment: Joe is absolutely right here. And I suspect the multiple gateways is the root cause. I don't understand why the Hyper-V host needs IP address/etc defined *at all* on the DMZ network. None of my hosts do, it isn't a requirement for the host to have an IP address in the DMZ for guests to have a connection on the DMZ.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is my setup of nic's. If Iunderstod your correctly i should only have one dns ip address in dns, that is my dc

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Network):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : alfa.local
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-17-EB-ED-F9-12
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c5b0:be85:f878:cb94%7(Preferred)
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.105(Preferred)
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19. januar 2019 22:55:44
       Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 27. januar 2019 22:55:43
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
       DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.100
       DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 137631723
       DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-DB-F6-86-34-17-EB-ED-F9-19
       DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                           fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                           fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
                                           10.0.0.100
                                           1.1.1.1
       NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

    Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DMZ vSwitch):

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dmzzone.dk
       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-17-EB-ED-F9-21
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::44e6:3b8c:5e07:8fcb%9(Preferred)
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 176.16.2.103(Preferred)
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19. januar 2019 22:55:44
       Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 20. januar 2019 22:55:44
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 176.16.2.1
       DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 176.16.2.1
       DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 238295019
       DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-DB-F6-86-34-17-EB-ED-F9-19
       DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 176.16.2.1
       NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DMZ network adapter is only used for the virtual machines, then you can simply uncheck the allow management operating system to share this network adapter.  This will solve your multiple NIC problem.

[image]